# Send Command line Commands to Remote Server

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-desktop, batch-file

I have a Active Directory Server that I have Remote Desktop Privileges on but not much else. I cant put any files let alone programs on this server. I was hopping it would be possible to send remote command prompt commands (perhaps through RDP).

Is there some way to get local command prompt to access this other server and inject command prompt commands? If so how?

Comment: Not possible to hack a remote server this way. Sorry. If you can start command prompt, then you can execute commands that way.

Comment: of course i can Remote Desktop the remote computer and run commands but there is no way to cut out the Remote desktop?

Comment: Unlikely. Ports need to be opened, and permissions etc needs to be set. Its not open by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`psexec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from [Microsoft Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

> PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems, complete with full interactivity for console applications, without having to manually install client software. PsExec's most powerful uses include launching interactive command-prompts on remote systems and remote-enabling tools like IpConfig that otherwise do not have the ability to show information about remote systems.
>
> ...
>
> **Examples**
>
> The following command launches an interactive command prompt on \marklap:
>
> ```
> psexec \\marklap cmd
> ```

If you can remote desktop to the computer, chances are you can use `psexec`.

Answer (score 0):

Does not appear to be possible.